# Strings and date fields in double quotes in csv files

Tags: python, csv

I want to write a csv file with alpha, alphanumeric and date time in double quotes, with remaining blank spaces, integer, decimal values not in quotes.

I wrote the following code and it is working as expected, but blanks spaces are also coming in double quotes. Can any one help me?

```
csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)

for row_input in csv_input:
    row_output = []
    for col in row_input:
        try:
            row_output.append(int(col))
        except ValueError, e:
            try:
                row_output.append(float(col))
            except ValueError, e:
                row_output.append(col)
                try:
                    row_output.append(long(col))
                except ValueError, e:
                    row_output.append(col)


    csv_output.writerow(row_output)
```

Comment: Please include a sample of the file you want to parse.

Comment: here is sample of files 24333,116,47,MCD,17996,112,654,CATECONSU,1,NIN,Y,Y,N,N,N,N,,100,,,,,,,,,

Comment: i am getting output like this 24333,116,47,"MCD","MCD",17996,112,654,"CATECONSU","CATECONSU",1,"NIN","NIN","Y","Y","Y","Y","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","N","","",100,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""

Comment: Plese [edit] your question. Don't put code into comments.